# Calculate 90 Days

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

I am using Sharepoint 2010.  I have a list, I will like to I.D. all files passed 90 days.  What is the formula for this action?

Comment: Can you give us more info? What column are you basing the date on? Creation Date? What do you mean by "I.D."?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a view in the list which will show items based on the formula. For example, if you want to see items which have been created during Past 90 days, the formula will be `Created is greater than or equal to [Today]-90`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are going to do with this.  If you are going to just look through the data then a view like Nadeem suggested is your solution.  If you are looking to use this in a workflow to do something with the data based on that date then it gets a bit more tricky.

List items won't update daily unless you manually change the record.  This prevents being able to have a calculated field that has a counter of days passed and checking the items that way.

The way that has worked best for me is:

- Create a calculated date field and take the column with the date you are running the calculation on and, in your case, add 90.

  - `= [Created] + 90`
- This will add 90 days to your original field and give you the day that the file passes its 90 days.
- With that you can create a site workflow, and have it run daily if you'd like, and do a check for `Today is equal to MyCalculatedField`. Then do what you need with the record.